# Pass rows from dataframe as arguments to custom regression function using dplyr/purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm writing a regression function which can take several arguments (I include just 3 arguments here for simplicity, but there will be tens of them). Ultimately I want to pass all possible combinations of arguments to the regression function and compile the estimates from the models. So I will first make the full set of combinations using `cross_df` then iterate over each row of the resulting dataframe, with each row containing the set of arguments to pass to the custom regression function (one argument per column). In the dataframe, I then want to create two new columns: one with the estimated coefficient for an independent variable, and one with the associated p-value.

Here's what I've tried:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(DeclareDesign)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(12345)

df <- fabricate(N = 100,
                oneDV = rnorm(N),
                anotherDV = draw_binary(prob = 0.5, N),
                X = draw_binary(prob = 0.5, N),
                M = rnorm(N))


myreg <- function(DV = NULL,
                  control = FALSE,
                  subset = FALSE) {

  dat <- df

  # declare dv
    dv <- DV

 if(subset) {
  dat %>% filter(M < median(M))} else {
  dat <- dat
  }  

  # controls
    if(control) {
      cntr <- "+ M"} else {
      cntr <- ""
      }

  # decalare formula
    frm <- paste0(dv, "~ X", cntr)
    out <- lm_robust(as.formula(frm), data = df)
    out$coef <- as.vector(out$coefficients[2])
    out$pval <- as.vector(out$p.value[2])

    return(out)
}

args <- list(
  DV = c("oneDV", "anotherDV"),
  control = c(T,F),
  double = c(T,F))

args %>% 
  purrr::cross_df() %>% 
  mutate(coef = myreg(DV, control, subset)$coef,
         pval = myreg(DV, control, subset)$pval)
```

As you can see, this isn't looping over each row as I want it to---the same result is showing for every row, even though every row is supposed to represent a separate model (8 distinct ones in this example). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `map2_dbl`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

args %>% 
    purrr::cross_df() %>% 
    mutate(coef = map2_dbl(DV, control, ~myreg(.x, .y)$coef), 
           pval = map2_dbl(DV, control, ~myreg(.x, .y)$pval))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   DV        control   coef  pval
#>   <chr>     <lgl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 oneDV     TRUE    0.120  0.569
#> 2 anotherDV TRUE    0.0957 0.354
#> 3 oneDV     FALSE   0.163  0.437
#> 4 anotherDV FALSE   0.0833 0.408
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Using `pmap` with more than 2 arguments:

```r
args %>% 
    purrr::cross_df() %>% 
    mutate(mod = pmap(., myreg), 
           coef = map_dbl(mod, ~.x$coef), 
           pval = map_dbl(mod, ~.x$pval))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 6
#>   DV        control subset mod           coef  pval
#>   <chr>     <lgl>   <lgl>  <list>       <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 oneDV     TRUE    TRUE   <lm_robst> -0.0917 0.678
#> 2 anotherDV TRUE    TRUE   <lm_robst> -0.0404 0.693
#> 3 oneDV     FALSE   TRUE   <lm_robst> -0.0825 0.706
#> 4 anotherDV FALSE   TRUE   <lm_robst> -0.0369 0.717
#> 5 oneDV     TRUE    FALSE  <lm_robst> -0.0917 0.678
#> 6 anotherDV TRUE    FALSE  <lm_robst> -0.0404 0.693
#> 7 oneDV     FALSE   FALSE  <lm_robst> -0.0825 0.706
#> 8 anotherDV FALSE   FALSE  <lm_robst> -0.0369 0.717
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, but how can I make it work for the case of more than 2 arguments/columns? Won't `map2_dbl` only let me pass two? As I mentioned, in the real application I have tens that I need to feed in.

Comment: `pmap` is your friend. Pass a list of arguments. Or perhaps use `nest` and pass the data.frame as a single argument instead.

Comment: In that case, you should use `purrr::pmap_dbl()`. You can pass any number of arguments.

Comment: I've edited the example to show the case of 3 arguments. I tried (e.g.) `coef = pmap_dbl(DV, control, double, ~myreg(.x, .y, .z)$coef)` but that gives an error. How does the `nest` approach work?

Comment: @lethalSinger If you check my edit, I show using `pmap`

Comment: @N. Williams sorry, there seems to be a problem still. I've revised the example to make more reproducible. Compare output in the first row [following the mutate] to `myreg(DV = "oneDV", control = T, subset = T)$coef` and `myreg(DV = "oneDV", control = T, subset = T)$pval`. In your example too you see the pattern of repeating pairs every other row. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @lethalSinger For some reason, when trying to extract `coef` and `pval` in one swoop and error occurs that I can't seem to figure out. However, in my most recent edit you'll see that if you first save the model in the dataframe and then extract `coef` and `pval` using `map_dbl()` you get the correct values. Note that I also changed the column `coef` to `subset`, when using `pmap()` the column names should be the same as the argument names for the function you are using.

Comment: Much appreciated, but output is still wrong: the bottom four rows of your tibble are repeated for coef and pval, and compare (e.g.) result from `myreg(DV = "oneDV", control = T, subset = F)`.

Comment: @lethalSinger The output is correct and the results line up with `myreg(DV = "oneDV", control = T, subset = F)`. Make sure you check before responding. You are getting repeating results because your functions is returning them that way.